# Flow and stationary points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is:

Observe the following flow:

$\phi_t (x,y)= \begin{pmatrix} x \cos((x^2+y^2)t)-y\sin((x^2+y^2)t) \\
x \sin((x^2+y^2)t)+y \cos((x^2+y^2)t)
\end{pmatrix} $

Find the stationary points and determine their stability.

I'm not really sure what to do, but I started with the following:

$\phi_t(x,y)=\vec{0}$

and found the following solution, $(x,y)=(0,0)$.
How can I determine the stability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know if it's from a dynamical systems point of view determine the jacobian of the right hand side, set $x, y=0$ and determine the eigenvalues of such matrix.

Doing this we get: (letting $r^2=x^2+y^2$)

$Df(x,y)=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(r^2t)-2x^2t\sin(r^2t)-2txy\cos(r^2t) & -2xyt\sin(r^2t)-\sin(r^2t)+2y^2cos(r^2t)  \\
\sin(r^2t)+2x^2t\cos(r^2t)-2xyt\cos(r^2t) & 2xyt\cos(r^2t)+\cos(r^2t)-2y^tcos(r^2t) \end{array} \right]$

At $(0,0)$: $Df(0,0)=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$ So $Df(0,0)$ is the identitiy matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}=1$ which have real part greater than zero, so (0,0) is hyperbolic and **unstable**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a stable point here, you will have to solve $\phi_t(x,y) = \left( \begin{array}{c}
x \\
y\end{array} \right)$.  Because you want the flow vector to be zero. Otherwise you will find the vector that directs you to $(0,0)$.

So solve:

$x\ cos((x^2+y^2)t)-y\ sin((x^2+y^2)t) = x$

and

$x\ sin((x^2+y^2)t)+y\ cos((x^2+y^2)t) = y$